# What are the steps for getting the pocketSphinx android demo to work?

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

I have simply cloned the demo project from the cmuSphinx site into android studio as the instructions say, but the project fails to build and run.

Can someone list a step by step guide for getting the demo to run properly?

Answer (score 2):

1.- Download project.

2.- Unzip it.

3.- In Android Studio Click in: File->Open...->Choose folder where you unziped the project and select it.

4.- Wait Android Studio configure the project  (Maybe you need to update Gradle).

5.- Only if aars files are  missing, add them: File-> new->Import module->Import .JAR/.AAR Package -> Next->choose build.gradle ->click in Ok->Finish

By default all files are configured by Android Studio.

6.- It´s highly important to use short names of folder and use near of root files system, for example in Windows put the proyect in c:/pocketsphinx/ Here is some snapshots:

[project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqxUz.png)

[project in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB3Oc.png)

Comment: Clone (download) project from here:https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android-demo